# Disable symfony cache / appDevDebugProjectContainer.php monster

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I am taking over a huge existing project. Now I am going after some bugs. 
But it is hard to understand what foreign code does when there is the symfony cache all over the place.

```
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
  RUN  '/usr/bin/php' '-S' '127.0.0.1:8000' '/Users/kb1/php/default/projectname/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php'
  ERR  [Thu Dec 17 10:13:08 2015] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The parameter "youtube_client_id" must be defined.' in /Users/kb1/php/default/projectname/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:4718
  ERR  Stack trace:
  ERR  #0 /Users/kb1/php/default/projectname/src/InfluencerBundle/Service/YouTube.php(74): appDevDebugProjectContainer->getParameter('youtube_client_...')
  ERR  #1 /Users/kb1/php/default/projectname/src/InfluencerBundle/Service/YouTube.php(56): InfluencerBundle\Service\YouTube->setConfigParams()
  ERR  #2 /Users/kb1/php/default/projectname/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(4275): InfluencerBundle\Service\YouTube->__construct(Object(appDevDebugProjectContainer))
  ERR  #3 /Users/kb1/php/default/projectname/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(305): appDevDebugProjectContainer->getYoutubeServiceService()
  ERR  #4 /Users/kb1/php/default/projectname/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(3937): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get in /Users/kb1/php/default/projectname/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 4718
```

Problem is, that almost every method is in this huge 5000 LOC appDevDebugProjectContainer.php Container.

Allready tried to [Disabling the Bootstrap File and Class Caching¶](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/debugging.html)
And although [used autoload.php and not bootstrap.php.cache](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/788)

this is my app_dev.php:

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
// $kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 4):

The dumped container cannot be avoided. Working with a non-dumped container would be slow as hell (especially for a big container), which is why the kernel does not have an option to bypass it.
And anyway, this would make the debugging even more painful. With the dumped container, you can see that the error comes from `getYoutubeServiceService`, i.e. the instantiation of the `youtube.service` service. Without a dumped container, you would just see a stack trace reaching ContainerBuilder without any info about which service was being instantiated at this time.

And btw, the stack trace shows you that the error happens in `InfluencerBundle\Service\YouTube->setConfigParams()`, which gets a non-existent parameter from the container.

On a side node, injecting the parameters in your service instead of injecting the whole container would be much cleaner (your service would not depend on the container itself but on its real dependencies) and would have given you a much easier to understand error message (because the container could have told you that your service uses a non-existent parameter when validating the container)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and this best practice.

Answer (score 2):

At first this bootstrap file may look intimidating, but I don't recommend you to disable it. If you take a closer look at the error messages, they always tell you exactly where to look at outside the bootstrap file.

For example, in your case the error is:

```
The parameter "youtube_client_id" must be defined.
```

And the origin of the error is in:

```
src/InfluencerBundle/Service/YouTube.php (line 74)
(which was called from) src/InfluencerBundle/Service/YouTube.php (line 56)
```

Comment: Thanks and yes - I know. I was not looking for this specific error, but  tried to work through an existing (big) codebase.